# SQL Server 2005 function to extract a substring match following a set string

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pattern-matching

Anybody have a nice tight and efficient SQL Server function that will return the fist string (terminated by a whitespace) following the first match of a given string.

I've got some code, but it's real ugly and probably slow.

For example, in `In test 12545 file:x12545.jpg appears to be good` given `file:` would return `x12345.jpg`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function dbo.extractAfter(@full nvarchar(max), @part nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
with returns null on null input
as begin
return ltrim(stuff(left(@full,charindex(' ', @full + ' ', charindex(@part,@full)+1)),
    1, charindex(@part,@full)+datalength(@part)/2 -1, ''))
end
go
```

Comment: Seems to work, but need some help tweaking it. Can we return null if no match? Also, can we include < as delimiter (due to possible hidden html tags) so that file:x12567.jpg<br> would not pick up the tag.  Thanks!

Comment: `datalength(@part)/2` could also be `length(@part + '.') - 1`. The former may be faster, while the latter is more universal (can work both with `nvarchar` and `varchar`).